# Getting List Index Out of Bounds when releasing form in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm developing an application with a security device that does some heavy checking at a separate thread. The return code differs from several situations, it's just do or die, and there is a specific case where the user has an old license and is given the chance to upgrade his license on the fly. If he chooses to do so, the process of upgrading the license takes some time, so I'm creating a simple form with just one label and exhibiting a simple message with this label, all at runtime, using a function that returns a TForm. This is the code for such function:

```
function TAuth.FrmWait: TForm;
var
  lbl : TLabel;
  frm : TForm;
  regn : HRGN;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(Application);
  with frm do
  begin
    Parent := F_MainForm;
    ClientWidth  := 479;
    ClientHeight := 97;
    Position := poMainFormCenter;
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    Visible := true;
    Color   := clWebFloralWhite;
    regn := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight,40,40);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, regn, True);
    with Font do
    begin
      Size := 12;
      Color := clNavy;
      Style := [fsBold];
    end;
  end;
  lbl := TLabel.Create(frm);
  with lbl do
  begin
    Parent := frm;
    Width  := 400;
    Height := 18;
    Top    := (frm.ClientHeight - Height) div 2;
    Left   := (frm.ClientWidth - Width) div 2;
    Caption := 'Please Wait...';
    ParentFont := true;
  end;
  result := frm;
  Application.ProcessMessages; //without this the label won't appear
end;
```

Thus far all good, but the real problem is when I actually use the FrmWait. The message gets displayed all right but when I dispose of it, I keep getting an Index out of bounds error, which is really odd, since I'm not using any lists. The code gets done here:

```
if _signal = 0 then
begin
  frm := FrmAguardar;
  frm.Show;
end;
{
    processing gets done here
}    
if _signal = 0 then
begin
  frm.Close();
  FreeAndNil(frm);
end;
```

The issues happens almost everytime at the `FreeAndNil`, to make things more confusing, it doesn't always happens. It happens like, around 8 out of 10 times or so (sometimes less , others more) . I tried looking every where, all I managed to find is that some memory overwrite might be happening, still, no way to work around this. Bear in mind that this is all being done at a worker thread , not the main one. Except for this one special case, all other validations work just fine.

I'm totally lost here. Could this be bad design on my end, could this be a delphi Bug? I'm using Delphi XE2 with windows 8.1

Thanks for everything!

Comment: "Bear in mind that this is all being done at a worker thread , not the main one." Are you saying that you are accessing the GUI from a thread without synchronizing with the main thread?

Comment: @LURD it looks like the form is created in the worker thread

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, indeed. Seems like one of the most common mistakes using Delphi. Is this the case with other languages like C++? I mean that some of the windows GUI parts are thread-safe, but I never looked close enough to tell if most things are.

Comment: @LURD C++ doesn't have a GUI framework. They exist as libraries only. It's possible to make UI libraries that have different threading rules. But it's not common. UI code is naturally single threaded. Supporting multiple threaded UI achieves what? Single threaded is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Use *File->New->Other->Delphi Files->Thread Object*, and read the *large autogenerated comment* at the top, which clearly says "don't access VCL controls from a thread other than the main thread without using Synchronize" (or read the TThread documentation in the help file).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, GUI in a single thread, yes. And also decoupled from business logic, to keep the implementation sane and easily testable.

Answer (score 5):

> Bear in mind that this is all being done at a worker thread, not the main one.

As has been stated so many times, all VCL access must be from the main thread. You break that rule and that's the cause of your problem.

Separate the UI code from the worker code. Put the worker code in a thread. Keep the UI code in the main thread.

Comment: Isn't there a way to sync VCL access from other treads to the main ?

Comment: Sure there are ways to do that. But all code that touches the VCL must execute in the main thread. For instance, all the code that builds your form must run in the main thread.

Comment: Now I seem to get it. I looked everywhere but didn't find anything about this VCL rule. I created the form at design time and had the thread just call it and everything works as expected now!

Comment: Well, depending on what you do to the form from the thread, that might be no good either

Comment: Raoni, if you "looked everywhere," but you didn't see anything forbidding accessing the VCL from other threads, then you must not have looked at anything that talks about the VCL and threads in the same document. That calls into question the thoroughness of your search. Now that you know what to look for, consider doing your search again. Don't stop until you find documents that mention this rule. Once you find them, remember the kind of search you had to do, and employ those same search tactics the next time you need to do research.